# Hollow World settings

Tags: campaign-settings

I'm aware of two RPGs with a hollow world setting (like Edgar Rice Burroughs' *At the Earth's Core* / *Pellucidar* series or Skartaris in DC's *Warlord* comics):

- *Hollow Earth Expeditions*
- the old D&D *Hollow World*

Are there any other settings or modules for RPGs with this as the campaign setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Epic of Aerth** a campaign supplement for the Dangerous Journeys RPG also featured not one but two hollow worlds.  The interior of Aerth is filled with dinosaurs, the interior of Phaeree is the home of the Unseelie court and associated races.

I had a look and you can still get copies of it through Amazon.

Answer (score 2):

There is a third "inside face of the shell" that I'm aware of: [BTRC](http://btrc.net/)'s [Epiphany](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/55490/epiphany). Epiphany is out of print, and one of the few BTRC products Greg isn't selling in PDF anymore.

A few more have "underground worlds" that are extensive but not truly hollow-worlds.

Comment: I couldn't remember if GURPS *Lands out of Time* had a hollow Earth variant. I was waiting for your answer to see if you included it. You didn't mention it, so obviously, it doesn't.

Comment: G:LOoT is after I quit doing GURPS... it might very well have it, I don't know. I've bought only one GURPS product since I bought the then just released G:Ogre...

Answer (score 2):

Hero Games came out with Pulp Hero adventure sets; one of which is called "Inner Earth".

Not quite Pellucidar, but it does have underground civilizations and other tropes of that sort.

RPGNow has the PDF for sale:

http://www.rpgnow.com/product_info.php?products_id=12504

Also, I highly recommend *Hollow Earth Expedition* from Exile Games.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that *[Lands of Mystery](http://www.yog-sothoth.com/wiki/index.php/Lands_of_Mystery)* (Aaron Allston, HERO Games 1985) for *Justice, Inc.* fits the bill.